# Как выровнять элемент по центру?

Tags: html, css

Ребят, всем привет.

Скачал готовый скрипт по затемнению картинки. Запарился, уже не могу сделать, чтобы картинка внутри была выровнена по центру. Принтсрикн:

[image]

Также ссылка на исходники. Выкладывать нет смысла весь код, т.к. проблема, скорей всего, в CSS.

[Скачать ТУТ.](http://kamnedsoft.kz/modules/CSS3-Hover-Effects.rar)

Ребята, помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Под "картинкой внутри" вы имеете ввиду кнопку "Подробнее"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь про кнопку "Подробнее", то в css файле secondeffect.css для селектора `.second-effect a.info` добавь `left: -10px;`.

http://c2n.me/3apyZ7I

Comment: не left: -10px, а margin-left: - (половины ширины кнопки) px

Comment: да там вроде как без разницы

Comment: судя по виду, у кнопки уже есть left:50%, так что разница есть и работать правильно будет только с margin-left

Comment: Скачал исходник, проблема там совсем другая :)

Comment: Спасибо мужики, оба помогли!

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте ширину к класса `.view a.info` в `css`, у вас картинка `47px` по ширине, а в стиле указано `57px`, поэтому и не по центру:

```
.view a.info {
   width: 47px;
}
```